# Correct procedure to add new client certificates?

Tags: openvpn, certificates

I managed to successfully set up my first OpenVPN server on a Webserver to restrict specific URLs to VPN users only by following one of the many guides I found on the Internet. Works like a charm.

All guides explain the exact same method to create the certificates.

1. Create Server Certificate
2. Create Client Certificate(s)
3. Generate Diffie Hellman Parameters

But what if I have to add new client certificates? Do I have to generate the Diffie Hellman Parameters after that again?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some hours diving into (Open)VPN and Diffie Hellman, I finally managed to figure it out.

The Diffie Hellman parameters are used by the OpenVPN Server to generate the session keys to establish the encrypted session. Once a session is established, other more specialized encryption methods are used to protect the data exchange during the its duration.

You can even generate a new .pem file during established sessions, they won't be affected at all.

So in the end it doesn't matter at all, if you generate the Diffie Hellman Parameters before or after the Client certs and there is no need to rebuild them after adding new ones.